# Add buttons to specific positions on an image

Tags: android, image, button

I was trying to add some buttons to some specific positions on an image. I am making use of webview to display the image because it embeds zoom in/out function; I have tried AbsoluteLayout to put buttons on it but when I zoom in, the button moved..

What should I do then? How can I make the button stick to one position of an image no matter how I zoom in and out?

Comment: AbsoluteLayout is deprecated.Try using Frame Layout.See here  http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems impossible to get the desired effect if you use `WebView`, since WebView's scaling does not affect the child view added to it.

If you are working on API 11+, you can use a `ViewGroup` such as `FrameLayout` to hold the image and the button, then call `View.setScaleX(float sf)` and `View.setScaleY(float sf)` on `FrameLayout` to scale it, so that all of its child will be scaled too.

I don't have a good solution for API level before 11, since `View` class does not contain transform information before API 11, maybe you can just recursively adjust the `LayoutParams` of all the Views to get the effect, I didn't try it, though.